# react native chat render the username

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm creating a react native chat app and I cant get the username in the messages

```
  // retrieve the messages from the Backend
  loadMessages(callback) {
    this.messagesRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");
    this.messagesRef.off();
    const onReceive = data => {
      const message = data.val();
      callback({
        id: data.key,
        text: message.text,
        createdAt: message.createdAt,
        user: {
          _id: message.user._id,
          name: message.user.Uemail,
          avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
        }

      });
    };
    this.messagesRef.limitToLast(20).on("child_added", onReceive);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some explanation to your answer. Right now, it is currently being marked as low quality by review due to length and content and is at risk of being deleted by the system. Thanks!